# homomorphism of sheaves. inverse image of sheaves induces a homomorphism

Tags: sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

Say we have two sheaves A and B and a homomorphism defined for each U: $\phi(U)$: A(U) $\rightarrow$ B(U) where A(U)= sections of A defined on U

Say we define $h^{-1}(A)= \lim_{h(U) \subset V} A(V)$.

There is supposed to be an induced homomorphism of sheaves $\phi_h: h^{-1}(A) \rightarrow h^{-1}(B)$. How to show that this is a well defined induced map??

Comment: Hint: use the universal property of the direct limit.

Comment: Can the same technique be used to prove: f:A $\rightarrow$ B, a group homomorphism, induces the map $f_t$: A $\otimes$ C $\rightarrow$ B $\otimes$ C. Where we define f': A $\times$ C $\rightarrow$ A $\rightarrow$ B $\rightarrow$ B $\otimes$ C and use the universal property to get an $f_t$ as stated before?